# How do I shift subtitle in OSX?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, subtitles, shift

I download subtitles for a video, but it's text was not in sync with my video sound and needs to be shifted forward for some seconds. How can I do it easily in OSX 10.6.?

I don't want suggestions for any extra applications like jubler. I want to know: Is it possible to do it with default application on OSX?

Answer (score 1):

Am1rr3zA -

If you are viewing subtitles in QuickTime you're already using other software (like Perian, etc).  My suggestion would be to use VLC which offers some subtitle shifting through Ctrl+H, Ctrl+J while viewing.

How far off are the subtitles?  The [second response to this post](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20071103080237904) talks about editing the SRT file to manually change the start and end times.  My understanding is again that VLC does better with this than QuickTime.

JDB

Comment: Tanx for your Answer I'll check it.